# How to use wp_editor and save its data in wp_posts table

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, tinymce, wp-editor

Recently I want to use wp_editor on a custom plugin where i add it inside a form and want to save its data in wp_posts table.

So, I have created a new post type car and adds a field with wp_editor for content of the car. Now i want to save this content inside wp_content column of wp_posts table. 
Here is my code

```
<form id="cartype" method="POST" action="" class="hcforms">
<div id="cw-post">
    <div class="cw-block cw-head">
        <p>Classwork Title</p>
        <input type="text" name="cw-title" placeholder="Enter Car Title">
    </div>
    <div class="cw-block cw-content wp-editor">
        <p>Classwork Content</p>
        <?php
            $content = '';
            $editor_id = 'cw-posts-content';
            wp_editor(
                $content, 
                $editor_id,
                array(
                  'media_buttons' => false,
                  //'textarea_name' => 'cw_content',
                  'textarea_rows' => 2,
                  'tabindex' => 2,
                  'quicktags' => false,
                  'tinymce' => array(
                    'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'bold, italic, ul',
                  ),
                )
            );
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="cw-block cw-submit">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="postCar"/>
        <input type="submit" name="aw-whats-new-submit" value="POST" onclick="return postCar()"/>
        <button type="button" class="cancel-form" onclick="closeForms()">cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
<?php wp_nonce_field( 'post_update', '_wpnonce_post_update' ); ?>
```

I am saving this post with the help of ajax. Here is my ajax code.

```
function postCar()
{
    var form_datacw = jQuery("#cartype").serialize();
    console.log(form_datacw);


    jQuery.ajax({
        action: "postCar",
        type:    "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        url:     ajaxurl,
        data:    form_datacw,
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery("#message-submit").html(data);
            setTimeout( function(){
                jQuery('#messageposts').hide();
                jQuery('#messageposts').remove();
                }, 
            9000);

        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

and calling this function inside functions.php to save data

```
function postCar()
{
    if( !empty($_POST['cw-title']) && !empty($_POST['cwcourse']) && !empty($_POST['cw-lesson-sel']) )
    {
        //IF ALL IS FILLED
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $post_cw = array(
        'post_title'    => $_POST['cw-title'],
        'post_content'  => '',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_type'     => 'car',
        'post_author'   => $user_id,
        );


        $cw_id = wp_insert_post( $post_cw );
        if ($cw_id) 
        {   

            $cw_post = array(
                  'ID'           => $cw_id,
                  'post_content'   => wp_kses_post($_POST['cw-posts-content']),
            );

            wp_update_post( $cw_post );

            $success = '';
            $success .= '<div id="messageposts" class="bp-messages bp-feedback success">
                    <span class="bp-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Success! Post submitted successfully.</p>
                </div>';
            echo $success;
        }
        else
        {
            $error = '';
            $error .= '<div id="messageposts" class="bp-messages bp-feedback error">
                        <span class="bp-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Something went wrong!</p>
                    </div>';
            echo $error;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $error = '';
        $error .= '<div id="messageposts" class="bp-messages bp-feedback error">
                    <span class="bp-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Please enter all fields content to post.</p>
                </div>';
        echo $error;
    }
    wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_postCar', 'postCar');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_postCar', 'postCar'); // not really needed
```

Everything is working fine but post_content is blank. I tried to get $_REQUEST and $_POST both are blank too. Please help. 
I need to use wp_editor to save user data in post_content column.

Thanks in advance!
John

Comment: WP already has an endpoint for posts in the REST API that you can use to create new posts, you can add one to your new CPT by using `show_in_rest` when registering your post type. Even then you can register your own REST API endpoint for AJAX. There's no need to use the ancient Admin AJAX API. Also, why are you creating the post with blank content then updating it? Why not just create it with the post content you want to begin with in a single step?

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you for your reply. I don't want to use REST API. Given example is just a scenario where i can't user REST API, also the updating post_content is just a test code. Nothing else. I would like to get content of wp_editor and want to save it in table. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like instead of creating custom editor fields, you'd be better off just using WP's built-in editor. If you want structured data, you can add regular (postmeta) custom fields or taxonomies. Or, consider using the Block Editor so things are formatted and templated as you wish - but all saved in wp_content rather than postmeta etc.